# Input fields sharing same values using ngfor

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular6

What I'm trying to do here is to dynamically add my input values for each input field onto my "tag" output. The problem I'm running into is that when I type and/or submit the values, all the input fields and "tag" outputs receive the same values. How can I fix this?

Thanks for taking the time in looking at this problem!

**index.html**

Note* - I cut most of the code down, just wanted to be direct as to what i need help with. The first line of code is to let you know that I am working within an *ngFor loop.

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let student of students; let i = index">    
<ul *ngFor="let tag of tags">
  <li class="tag">{{ tag }}</li>
</ul>
<input
  type="text"
  name="tagInput"
  class="moreInfo tagInput"
  placeholder="Add a tag"
  [(ngModel)]="tagInput"
  (keydown.enter)="onAddTag($event)">
</div>
```

**ts file**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

tagInput = '';
tags = [];

onAddTag(event){
  this.tags.push(this.tagInput);
  this.tagInput = '';
}
```